# Observer's completion handler not called, how to check in code

Tags: swift, authentication, firebase

I use Firebase and Swift, for a custom auth with Instagram.

I have this problem now, [Remove a user through dashboard, but the user is still logged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383368/remove-a-user-through-dashboard-but-the-user-is-still-logged-in)

When I start the app, I have this listener:

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener {
```

in which I am setting an observer:

```
ref.child("users/\(user.uid)").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
        ..........
    }, withCancel: { error in
        print(error)
    })
```

`with` and `withCancel` handlers are not executed, because user's token does not exist anymore. ( very weird IMO that even `withCancel` does not execute).

I have to catch this situation in code, to force a logout, like the post stated:

> check whether you can read to your users area, and if there's nothing there, force a log out.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reporting a bug report to Firebase. 
I will post the response, since it may help someone in the future.

The guys from Firebase responded this,

> The behavior you have described is intended by design. A user's
>   session persists indefinitely even if you have deleted the user from
>   the application. To help you with this scenario, you may check on the
>   following StackOverflow posts that might give you more information on
>   how to handle this one.
>
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207670
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384430
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203301

More on this, I have insisted with the cancel block, why it did not execute:

*I don’t understrand why `withCancel` completion handler is not called. 
from this:*

```
 ref.child("users/\(user.uid)").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in 
     print(snapshot) 
     .......... 
     }, withCancel: { error in 
        print(error)  
     })
```

*When I put breakpoints on both prints, app does not stop. So, even `withCancel` is not called.*

**The answer:**

> Going to your `withCancel` completion handler inquiry, let me just
>   give you a bit of information here. Cancel blocks are called if the
>   client is unauthenticated and no longer has permission to receive
>   events. Additionally, it is also worth mentioning that cancel blocks
>   are not called during offline mode as Firebase is designed to work
>   well in this condition. You may check our document for further
>   details.